# Convergent or divergent series? Asymptotic of the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

\begin{align}
A&=\sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{b^n}{(n+1)^3}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}b^{n}}{n!}\frac{1}{(1+n)^{3}} = 1\,{}_{3}F_{3}(1,1,1;2,2,2;-b)
\end{align}
The series is convergent or divergent when b ~ 10^6? Can we survey the asymptotic of this series when b large? 
I have use the wolfarm alpha and see that it come to zero for b large! However it's not help for my problem. I need an approximation when b large for this series so any suggestions for me to do that? ${}_{3}F_{3}(1,1,1;2,2,2;-b)$ is the generalized hypergeometric function.

Comment: Did you try wolfram alpha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see where the factor $2$ is coming from. To me
$$A=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{b^n}{(n+1)^3}=\, _3F_3(1,1,1;2,2,2;-b)$$

Playing with a CAS (**C**omputer **A**lgebra **S**ystem)  I arrived to
$$A=\frac{6 \log ^2(b)+12 \gamma  \log (b)+(\pi ^2+6 \gamma ^2)}{12 b}-\frac{e^{-b}}{b^3}\left(1-\frac{3}{b}+\frac{11}{b^2}-\frac{50}{b^3}+\frac{274}{b^4}+\cdots \right)$$ and then the asymptotics
$$A\simeq\frac{6 \log ^2(b)+12 \gamma  \log (b)+(\pi ^2+6 \gamma ^2)}{12 b}$$
which does not seem  bad at all (the table was generated for twenty significant figures).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 b & \text{approximation} & \text{exact}\\
  10 & 0.49690932360120875139 & 0.49690928832388243555 \\
 20 & 0.36027227594404510777 & 0.36027227594382029864 \\
 30 & 0.29121174059860656362 & 0.29121174059860656046 \\
 40 & 0.24805627039169795554 & 0.24805627039169795554 \\
 50 & 0.21798197906031610042 & 0.21798197906031610042 \\
 60 & 0.19557007518743034227 & 0.19557007518743034227 \\
 70 & 0.17808871303080732581 & 0.17808871303080732581 \\
 80 & 0.16399386407966419640 & 0.16399386407966419640 \\
 90 & 0.15233955734129875868 & 0.15233955734129875868 \\
 100 & 0.14251028587174600483 & 0.14251028587174600483 \\
 200 & 0.090417056176257986847 & 0.090417056176257986847 \\
 300 & 0.068493119493293235309 & 0.068493119493293235309 \\
 400 & 0.055990617243116989201 & 0.055990617243116989201 \\
 500 & 0.047773804098897067512 & 0.047773804098897067512 \\
 600 & 0.041903030844139627443 & 0.041903030844139627443 \\
 700 & 0.037469669949770873800 & 0.037469669949770873800 \\
 800 & 0.033986919466450244270 & 0.033986919466450244270 \\
 900 & 0.031168657855126580756 & 0.031168657855126580756 \\
 1000 & 0.028834862048815511463 & 0.028834862048815511463 \\
 2000 & 0.017131637531050345297 & 0.017131637531050345297 \\
 3000 & 0.012553805862832047429 & 0.012553805862832047429 \\
 4000 & 0.010043035272326017788 & 0.010043035272326017788 \\
 5000 & 0.0084353206512719321002 & 0.0084353206512719321002 \\
 6000 & 0.0073085551020333550676 & 0.0073085551020333550676 \\
 7000 & 0.0064704608754287297893 & 0.0064704608754287297893 \\
 8000 & 0.0058201825163032066414 & 0.0058201825163032066414 \\
 9000 & 0.0052994357876654838989 & 0.0052994357876654838989 \\
 10000 & 0.0048720593620934820453 & 0.0048720593620934820453
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If you expand the first terms (say, up to $7$)
$$\sum_{n=0}^{7} \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \frac{b^n}{(n+1)^3}=1-\frac{b}{8}+\frac{b^2}{54}-\frac{b^3}{384}+\frac{b^4}{3000}-\frac{b^5}{25920}+\frac{b^6}{246960}-\frac{b^7}{2580480}$$ you should find that sequence $\{1, 8, 54, 384, 3000, 25920, 246960, 2580480, 29393280\}$ is [$A002775$](http://oeis.org/search?q=8%2C54%2C384%2C3000&sort=&language=&go=Search) in $OEIS$; please read the very first comment in the linked page.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand what CAS is? and How can you limit the expansion like that, can you do it step by step please?

Comment: @HongAnPham. **C**omputer **A**lgebra **S**ystem.  Have a look to my edit.

Comment: Can you tell me what CAS did you use here?

Answer (score 1):

That series is in fact convergent for all $b\in\mathbb{R}$; you are dividing by a factorial, and generally speaking all factorials dominate all exponentials. You can learn more about this phenomenon by reading up on [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Answer (score 1):

The parameters of the hypergeometric function come from $(1)_n/(2)_n = 1/(n + 1)$. Here is a sketch of how an asymptotic estimate can be derived. We have
$${_3\hspace{-1px}F_3}(1, 1, 1; 2, 2, 2; -b) =
G_{3, 4}^{1, 3} \left( b \middle| {0, 0, 0 \atop 0, -1, -1, -1} \right) =
\frac 1 {2 \pi i} \int_C
 \frac {\Gamma(-y) \Gamma^3(1 + y)} {\Gamma^3(2 + y)} b^y dy.$$
The poles of $\Gamma(-y)$ are on the rhs of the contour $C$. We can extend the contour indefinitely to the left to make $y$ large everywhere on $C$, replace $\Gamma(-y)$ with its asymptotic approximation and estimate the integral by applying the steepest descent method. The saddle point will be at $y = -b$, thus the integral will be exponentially small in $b$. Now we just need to add the contribution from the pole at $y = -1$, which appeared when moving the contour:
$$\operatorname*{Res}_{y = -1}
 \frac {\Gamma(-y) \Gamma^3(1 + y)} {\Gamma^3(2 + y)} b^y =
\frac {6 \ln^2 b + 12 \gamma \ln b + \pi^2 + 6 \gamma^2} {12 b}.$$